# Trying to create an accordion table with Bootstrap, but cells get corrupted on click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, accordion

I'm trying to create a table that reveals and hides additional rows of information, accordion-style. It's working for the most part, but unfortunately the cell layout gets all screwed up whenever you reveal a row.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3y7118ek/)

As you can see, when you click a row, all the new cells become compressed to the left instead of stretching out across the row like normal. I've been trying to debug in Chrome but I can't figure out why it's doing this.

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="table-scrollable">
        <table id="tbl-sample-values" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size:85%;">
            <thead>
                <tr style="color: red;">
                    <th>Step #</th>
                    <th>Processing Step</th>
                    <th>Barcode</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable">
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Parts Inspection</td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="accordion" class="collapse">
                    <td>9.1</td>
                    <td>Handle silicon electrodes...</td>
                    <td>[Barcode here]</td>
                </tr>

                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion2" class="clickable">
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td colspan="2">IPA Clean</td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="accordion2" class="collapse">
                    <td>10.1</td>
                    <td>Place part with frontside facing up...</td>
                    <td>[Barcode here]</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of bootstrap CSS. When you expand a row its get `.in` class and this style:

```
.collapse.in {
    display: block;
}
```

You have to add custom CSS:

```
tr.collapse.in {
    display: table-row;
}
```

or update your bootstrap version - later versions already include this.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3y7118ek/3/)